# slick.js slider - threshold mouse drag

Tags: javascript, slider, slick.js

I would like to change the threshold of the mouse drag in slick slider. The behavior should be similar to the `touchThreshold` option for touch.

Any ideas how I could do this? I tried to edit the plugin, but couldn't really understand where I would do that.

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably add a method to Slick that mimics the slidesToScroll setting, but uses the value as a max-scroll instead of a hard set rule. If you set up a fiddle for what you're looking at, I could help out.

Comment: @NominalAeon https://jsfiddle.net/vinnni/uz9a1z7u/8/ I would like to set the threshold on drag smaller than default.